Kitchen half-wall/pony-wall receptacle height
I'd like to add some receptacles and a disposal switch to a half-wall dividing the kitchen and living rooms.
The original height of the wall is about 39-3/4", the countertop height will be around 36".
I didn't feel like there was enough space to place vertically orientated receptacles, so I tried to raise the wall about 3" to about 43" and installed receptacles centered around halfway between the countertop and the top of the wall--that is, about 38" from the floor and 2" from the countertop.
I'm still not sure if there is enough space.
Are there any recommendations or best practices on the height of receptacles on a half wall countertop?
I've found general recommendations that countertop receptacles are generally placed about 42" high, but also that such half walls tend to range between 36-42" in height. Are there any codes or best practices specific to half-wall receptacles? Are the receptacles too low and should I consider raising the wall further?


There are strict regulations in the Code for mounting a Power outlet wrt Sink. Familiarize your self with those since the outlet on the right might not be up to the code.

Can you reference those relevant regulations?

There's a maximum height above the countertop specified in code, but no minimum. Therefore, here are the relevant considerations as I see them:

I'd want them up as much as possible to avoid splash hazards.

I'd want them at least an inch or so below the top of the finished wall so you don't have plugs, transformers, or other devices protruding into the opening area.


I'd consider mounting the boxes horizontally to achieve the goals above. I would not be concerned that they don't align with other boxes in the area, but I'd be precise in my heights so these are visually aligned.

I'd wonder what devices these outlets are supposed to power before being concerned about protruding into the open area.  It looks like there'll be a sink here (a separate issue) but if the plug is for a something like a stand mixer or coffee machine, does it really matter if the plug sticks up?
